# How to allow people to login to mywebsite using their fb account

Tags: web, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-login

I am trying to build my first App, allowing people to login to mywebsite using their fb account. However, I keep getting this message

> you have not authorized any apps to interact with your Facebook account

How can I authorize apps to interact with fb account?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps found in this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/)

If you're still having issues after that, post more details about where you are in the steps.